# Selenium XPath for bold <b></b> tag

Tags: selenium, xpath

Below is the HTML containing the b (bold) tags i want to get the XPath for.

```html
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" style="VERTICAL-ALIGN: top" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1">..</td>
        <td align="left" style="VERTICAL-ALIGN: top" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1">
          <div class="get-HTML" __listner=" <DIV class=gwt-HTML><B>Xyz</B></DIV>">
            <b>Xyz</b>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td align="left" style="VERTICAL-ALIGN: top" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1">
          <div class="get-HTML" __listner=" <DIV class=gwt-HTML><B>01/01/2019</B></DIV>">
            <b>01/01/2019</b>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td align="left" style="VERTICAL-ALIGN: top" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1">..</td>
        <td align="left" style="VERTICAL-ALIGN: top" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1">
          <div class="get-HTML" __listner=" <DIV class=gwt-HTML><B>Abc</B></DIV>">
            <b>Abc</b>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

I came up with this xpath: `//div[@class='get-HTML']/b` but there are many other b tags.

For example if I had to read the text at the below tag, how do I be precise?

```html
<td align="left" style="VERTICAL-ALIGN: top" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1">
    <div class="get-HTML" __listner="<DIV class=gwt-HTML><B>01/01/2019</B></DIV>">
        <b>01/01/2019</b>
    </div>`
```

Tried this xpath but it didnt work:

```
//div[@class='get-HTML']/b[2]
```

Can you please help me crack this xpath?

Comment: Can you try this xpath and let me know whether this works or not?
```(//div[@class='get-HTML']/b)[2]```

Comment: Please try this xpath: `//b[text() and ./parent::*[@class='get-HTML']]`

Answer (score 1):

Because the HTML tree is identical above all `b` elements -- meaning, `tr/td/div/b` will always retrieve 3 different `b` elements, you will need to use an index to access the desired element.

Depending on the `b` tag you want to retrieve, you will need to use the index of `td` elements to get the tag, because there are multiple `td` elements on the same level:

```
//tr/td[index]/div/b
```

Applying this example, we can retrieve `b` tags as such:

To get `Xyz`: `//tr/td[2]/div/b`

To get `01/01/2019`: `//tr/td[3]/div/b`

To get `abc`: `//tr/td[5]/div/b`

Alternatively, if you would like to get the `b` tag based on its text, the path is different:

```
//b[text()='xyz']
```

However, this will only get you one `b` element, and you must know its text beforehand, so this approach is not desirable if you do not know the text inside the `b` elements.

Comment: Hi there, I had to use IE browser and my testing and dont have any privilege to use other browers at work. In IE im using MRI to validate elements. If i give below xpath it does not identify: //tr/td[3]/div/b          It gives 0 elements found. Any idea why?

Comment: I am not really sure, I tested out the XPath in my browser and it was successful. If you post the full HTML or a link to the page you are automating, this will help track Down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be really specific include more parent elements in your XPath.

Easy trick to always get the correct XPath: Use Google Chrome Inspector > Select element > Right click HTML tag > Copy > XPath

In this case:

```html
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" style="VERTICAL-ALIGN: top" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1">..</td>
      <td align="left" style="VERTICAL-ALIGN: top" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1">
        <div class="get-HTML" __listner=" <DIV class=gwt-HTML><B>Xyz</B></DIV>">
          <b>Xyz</b>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td align="left" style="VERTICAL-ALIGN: top" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1">
        <div class="get-HTML" __listner=" <DIV class=gwt-HTML><B>01/01/2019</B></DIV>">
          <b>01/01/2019</b>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td align="left" style="VERTICAL-ALIGN: top" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1">..</td>
      <td align="left" style="VERTICAL-ALIGN: top" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1">
        <div class="get-HTML" __listner=" <DIV class=gwt-HTML><B>Abc</B></DIV>">
          <b>Abc</b>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

The XPath for the third b tag is: `/html/body/div[3]/b`

In your case, maybe you need to remove the `/html/body/` maybe not. It depends on what parent elements your HTML code is in.

Note: so the XPath changes when you use different parent elements if you use this precise method. eg: It can be more difficult to implement on dynamically generated pages.